# Let user edit float type data in Palantir

Tags: palantir-foundry

I'm currently looking for a way to let users do a simulation on Palantir.

The concept is the following: users are given a set of products for which we have the expected volumes for the next 12 months. They then specify the price they want to apply on the different month and see the result.

To implement this, I need to let them edit float type data in a seamless way. The best solution will be to let them do the modification and see the results in the same page.

I tried using object types and action types to do that. Unfortunately, actions don't support modification on float type data :

> Supported property types
> Actions does not currently support editing float, byte, short, or time series property types. Contact your Palantir representative if your workflow requires editing these types.

Workshop inline edits are also not possible in this case (since it is an action type too).

Is there a way to do this with object types or datasets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the type to "double" which is editable.